# Rename variables using a list of variable names

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with column names:

```
  COL1     COL2
   10       5
   15       7
```

With another dataframe that has a more understandable set of variables:

```
Reference    Name
   COL1     Length
   COL2     Height
```

Is there a way to rename the first df using the other df refernce to provide me with:

```
Length   Height
  10       5
  15       7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
names(df1) <-  df2$Name[match(df2$Reference, names(df1))]
names(df1)
#[1] "Length" "Height"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(COL1 = c(10L, 15L), COL2 = c(5L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

df2 <- structure(list(Reference = c("COL1", "COL2"), Name = c("Length", 
"Height")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```